# Mockito - Not able to Mock ResultSet

Tags: scala, mockito, scalatest

I am writing a test case where I am trying to mock a Resultset. To do that I already have my mocks in place

```
  val mockedResultSet = mock[ResultSet]
  val mockedRow = mock[Row]
```

Now when I invoke certain functions on this mocked object like .one() or .all() or .isExhausted on my ResultSet, I am able to get the desired output. For ex

```
  doReturn(mockedRow).when(mockedResultSet).one()
```

or

```
  doReturn(true).when(mockedResultSet).isExhausted
```

But, there are some methods in which I am directly applying a map function on the resultSet instead of applying .all() on it. For ex:-

```
   val results = executeDBStatement(dBConnection, queryBuilderStmt)
    if (!results.isExhausted) {
      val res = results.map(row => {        
      // iterate over the result and create a list of case classes
      }
      )
    }
```

Here I am not able to mock the map function behavior of ResultSet. Please let me know how I can mock the resultSet in such situations. Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: Mocking JDBC is challenging, as it requires to mock coherently a big bunch of related classes. I would suggest to have a look at the framework [Acolyte](http://acolyte.eu.org/) which offer a JDBC driver to mock/create dev driven connection, fully isolated w\o any storage that can be used for unit testing

Answer (score 1):

It's usually not advisable to mock objects that you don't own (check [this](https://github.com/testdouble/contributing-tests/wiki/Don't-mock-what-you-don't-own) article for more detail)

So ideally in your scenario you would have a repository class for which you'd write integration test against an in-memory database (I'm assuming you are using SQL with JDBC as you don't specify) so you have your DB interactions encapsulated there and properly tested and then you can go and mock said repository when you have to test any other class in your system that depends on in.

Now, if for some reason you still wanna mock the ResultSet, it would be nice to know what library are you using and what exact error are you getting while trying to stub the map function.